# Sl4a recognize speech in background

Tags: android, python, speech-recognition, sl4a, qpython

I am started programming sl4a (in QPython) and it is really great. Now I tried to use the droid.recognizeSpeech function. This one works fine too, but I like to get it in the background listening for a keyword, like Google's 'OK Google'.
So I looked around, but cannot find anything. I don't know how I can implement it.
So I ask you, can someone tell me, if it is possible, how to make recognize speech always listening in the background waiting for a keyword?

Comment: You need to decompose this task. First try to implement the listener for the keyword with [PocketsphinxAndroid](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid) in Java. Second, implement call required java code from sl4a. You can run keyword search in a service and only get detection notifications with intent messaging.

Comment: Ok, is if I combine  java and sl4a. But I am looking for a solution for sl4a only.

Answer (score 2):

I've toyed with the idea of doing this, but never found any useful practical application for it. So here's a summary of my research, I hope it's enough to get you started:
1. The Speech Recognizer facade has multiple parameters. Usually, everyone puts "none" in all of them except the first. Here's the facade in it's actuality:

> **recognizeSpeech**:
>   Recognizes user's speech and returns the most likely result. 
>   **prompt (String)** text prompt to show to the user when asking them to speak (optional) 
>   **language (String)** language override to inform the recognizer that it should expect speech in a language different than the one set in the java.util.Locale.getDefault() (optional)
>  
>   **languageModel (String)** informs the recognizer which speech model to prefer (see android.speech.RecognizeIntent) (optional)
>   **returns: (String)** An empty string in case the speech cannot be recognized.

So you're looking for the languageModel in this case, that option is restricted to two types. A web search model and a free-form speech model. You're looking for the free-form speech model in this case. Here's a little more info on this model from the horse's mouth:
[Google on the Free-Form Language Model](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html#LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM)

Once you've looked at the free-form speech model, what should help you is Chrome's continuous speech recognition model, which should share a lot of the same characteristics of the Free-Form language model. Hope this helps set you on the right direction